# How to make a list with no duplicates

Tags: python, arrays, list

OK so I will start with what I know. I know you can make lists and then create copy of those lists that remove all/dont include the list item doubles. What I'm looking for is a list that could check itself and not include the duplicates.

The code below is what I am trying to do but the links list does not exist yet. So I get a NameError. Again I know I can make a new list and tell it not to include the items but I'm looking for a nice one line way to accomplish this goal. And maybe it requires me to iterate over the list a little different and takes 2 lines, but the goal is to create a list with no duplicates without relying on writing over the list or making a new one. Basically something that only needs to iterate over the list one time (during creation).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import sys 
import re

try: 
    page = requests.get(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    page = requests.get("https://medium.com")

body = bs4(page.content, "html.parser")
links = [a['href'] for a in body.find_all("a") if a['href'] not in links]
```

Comment: Does your list of objects need to be in any particular order?

Comment: You can quickly create a `set` from the current list items and then check against while updating the list with potentially new members in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use set and convert them back to lists?

```py
links = list(set([a['href'] for a in body.find_all("a")]))
```

Comment: i actually just figured out i could do `links = []
for i in [a['href'] for a in body.find_all("a")]:
    try: 
        links.index(i)
    except:
        links.append(i) ` but your way is better/exactly what i need

Comment: Note, you can just use a set-comprehension, so `list({a['href'] for a in body.find_all("a")})`

Comment: to be completely honest a set is exactly what i need. a set will also take care of any duplicates when added. so links is actually now a set in my code. `list = {}` so that later on i can do: `for i in new_links_comming_in: links.add(i)` its in a repo: https://github.com/icarus612/spiderPY-medium if you wanna check it out.